# I am getting an error: "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'text_to_print' referenced before assignment"

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite, tkinter

```
def search():

        def back():
            searchwindow.destroy()

        def submit():
            inputID = ID.get()
            if inputID == "":
                messagebox.showerror("Error", "Please Enter An ID")
            elif len(inputID) != 6:
                messagebox.showerror("Error", "ID Must Be 6 Characters Long")
            else:
                cursor.execute(("SELECT * FROM tblRoomAllocation WHERE roomID = ?"), (inputID,))
                records = cursor.fetchall()
                for record in records:
                    text_to_print = str(record[0]) + " | " + str(record[1]) + " | " + str(record[2]) + " | " + str(record[3]) + " | " + str(record[4]) 
                messagebox.showinfo("Search Results", text_to_print)
```

I tried to make "text_to_print" global and it is still giving me the same error. I am only a beginner to this so please help out. Thank you for any help.

Comment: The error raised because there is no record returned from the SQL statement.  You need to initialize `text_to_print` to empty string before the for loop.

Comment: Even though there are records returned, `text_to_print` contains only the last record in the result.

Answer (score 1):

Put the last line in the else:

```
for record in records:
    text_to_print = str(record[0]) + " | " + str(record[1]) + " | " + str(record[2]) + " | " + str(record[3]) + " | " + str(record[4]) 
if records:
     messagebox.showinfo("Search Results", text_to_print)
```

Comment: Your solution will get the same error if there is no record returned from the SQL statement.

Comment: @acw1668 now does it?

Comment: @JERRYSANTHOSH if this helped you, dont forget to tick :)